# IllegalArgumentException Joda Time

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jodatime

I am getting the following error:

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with
> path [/main] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested
> exception is
>
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format:
> "2015-05-16T00:00:00.000-07:00" is malformed at
> "15-05-16T00:00:00.000-07:00"] with root cause
>
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format:
> "2015-05-16T00:00:00.000-07:00" is malformed at
> "15-05-16T00:00:00.000-07:00"
>
> at
> org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime(DateTimeFormatter.java:899)

My code is:

```
private DateTime parseDateTime(String givenTime, Integer timezoneOffset)
{
    if (givenTime == null || givenTime .length() == 0) return null;
    DateTimeZone tdz = DateTimeZone.getDefault();

    if (timezoneOffset != null)
    {
        tdz = DateTimeZone.forOffsetHoursMinutes(timezoneOffset / 60, timezoneOffset % 60);
    }

    DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormat.shortDateTime().withZone(tdz);
    return f.parseDateTime(givenTime);
}
```

The html mapping for that element is:

```
<input class="dateTimePicker" type="text" id="dateTime" name="schedule.dateTime" />
```

The dateTime variable is of DateTime type and while sending to the above function, I am sending a schedule.getDateTime().toString() value.

The inputs (when debugged) to this method are :

timezoneOffset = -420

givenTime = "2015-05-16T11:00:00.000-07:00"

The value of givenTime is the one I have selected in UI and the time zone value must be correct coz I am in PST. Please help me with this...

Comment: You should try to use `shortDateTime` to format current date and see that (AFAIK) the output does **not** look like what you're trying to parse

Comment: Here, we are trying to convert the time zone to server default value. Like if the record is created at 03:00 CST and the server stores PST, we try to convert the time to 01:00 PST while saving.